# How do I get value corresponding to latest date in group to fill in null values in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, window-functions

I have the following table in Oracle SQL:

```
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| OWNER_CHANGE_DATE |     CAR      | LICENSE_PLATE |   OWNER_NAME    | COLOR_CHANGE_DATE | COLOR  |
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| 1-Jan-20          | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Doe        | 2-Feb-20          | red    |
| 1-Jan-20          | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Doe        | 21-Mar-20         | orange |
| 1-Jan-20          | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Doe        | 22-Mar-20         | green  |
| 23-Mar-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe        | 23-Mar-20         | blue   |
| 23-Mar-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe        | 24-Mar-20         | pink   |
| 23-Mar-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe        | 25-Mar-20         | purple |
| 23-Mar-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe        | 26-Mar-20         | brown  |
| 2-Jun-20          | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jack Doe        | (null)            | (null) |
| 12-Jul-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Steve Doe       | (null)            | (null) |
| 1-Jan-19          | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Adam Baker      | 1-Jan-19          | red    |
| 1-Jan-19          | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Adam Baker      | 5-Jan-19          | blue   |
| 3-Feb-19          | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Frank Evans     | 14-Feb-19         | red    |
| 19-Apr-19         | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Clark Davis     | (null)            | (null) |
| 11-Aug-19         | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Joe Bryant      | (null)            | (null) |
| 1-Oct-19          | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Jennifer Smith  | (null)            | (null) |
| 30-Nov-19         | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | William Johnson | (null)            | (null) |
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Notice that there are six rows with `NULL` values for `COLOR_CHANGE_DATE` and `COLOR`. I want to fill those values with the latest color and date based on car. For example, once I fill in the `NULL` values, I want the resulting table to look like the following:

```
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| OWNER_CHANGE_DATE |     CAR      | LICENSE_PLATE |   OWNER_NAME    | COLOR_CHANGE_DATE | COLOR  |
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| 1-Jan-20          | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Doe        | 2-Feb-20          | red    |
| 1-Jan-20          | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Doe        | 21-Mar-20         | orange |
| 1-Jan-20          | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Doe        | 22-Mar-20         | green  |
| 23-Mar-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe        | 23-Mar-20         | blue   |
| 23-Mar-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe        | 24-Mar-20         | pink   |
| 23-Mar-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe        | 25-Mar-20         | purple |
| 23-Mar-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe        | 26-Mar-20         | brown  |
| 2-Jun-20          | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jack Doe        | 26-Mar-20         | brown  |
| 12-Jul-20         | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Steve Doe       | 26-Mar-20         | brown  |
| 1-Jan-19          | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Adam Baker      | 1-Jan-19          | red    |
| 1-Jan-19          | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Adam Baker      | 5-Jan-19          | blue   |
| 3-Feb-19          | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Frank Evans     | 14-Feb-19         | red    |
| 19-Apr-19         | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Clark Davis     | 14-Feb-19         | red    |
| 11-Aug-19         | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Joe Bryant      | 14-Feb-19         | red    |
| 1-Oct-19          | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Jennifer Smith  | 14-Feb-19         | red    |
| 30-Nov-19         | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | William Johnson | 14-Feb-19         | red    |
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Note that the `NULL` values for the six rows have been filled in with the latest `COLOR_CHANGE_DATE` and `COLOR` for each `CAR`. That is, for `Ford F150`, the `NULL` values are replaced with the latest `COLOR_CHANGE_DATE`= `26-Mar-20` and `COLOR` = `brown`.

There can be indefinite number of owners that do not have corresponding `COLOR` and `COLOR_CHANGE_DATE`s. If an owner does not have `COLOR` and `COLOR_CHANGE_DATE`s, then I need to fill in the `NULL` values with the latest `COLOR_CHANGE_DATE` and `COLOR` for each car.

Can you show me how to do this in Oracle SQL?

Below is the SQL query to generate the sample table for your convenience.

```
with a as (
            select to_date('1/1/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   ,  'Ford F150' as car   
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate 
                   , 'John Doe' as owner_name 
                   , to_date('2/2/2020 12:43', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'red' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('1/1/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Ford F150' as car
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate
                   , 'John Doe' as owner_name
                   , to_date('3/21/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'orange' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('1/1/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Ford F150' as car
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate
                   , 'John Doe' as owner_name
                   , to_date('3/22/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'green' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('3/23/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Ford F150' as car
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate
                   , 'Jane Doe' as owner_name
                   , to_date('3/23/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'blue' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('3/23/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Ford F150' as car
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate
                   , 'Jane Doe' as owner_name
                   , to_date('3/24/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'pink' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('3/23/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Ford F150' as car
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate
                   , 'Jane Doe' as owner_name
                   , to_date('3/25/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'purple' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('3/23/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Ford F150' as car
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate
                   , 'Jane Doe' as owner_name
                   , to_date('3/26/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'brown' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('6/2/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Ford F150' as car
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate
                   , 'Jack Doe' as owner_name
                   , null color_change_date
                   , null color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('7/12/2020 8:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Ford F150' as car
                   , '3892A84' as license_plate
                   , 'Steve Doe' as owner_name
                   , null color_change_date
                   , null color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('1/1/2019 10:27', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Toyota Camry' as car
                   , '894A839' as license_plate
                   , 'Adam Baker' as owner_name
                   , to_date('1/1/2019 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'red' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('1/1/2019 10:27', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Toyota Camry' as car
                   , '894A839' as license_plate
                   , 'Adam Baker' as owner_name
                   , to_date('1/5/2019 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'blue' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('2/3/2019 10:27', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Toyota Camry' as car
                   , '894A839' as license_plate
                   , 'Frank Evans' as owner_name
                   , to_date('2/14/2019 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') color_change_date
                   , 'red' color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('4/19/2019 10:27', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Toyota Camry' as car
                   , '894A839' as license_plate
                   , 'Clark Davis' as owner_name
                   , null color_change_date
                   , null color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('8/11/2019 10:27', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Toyota Camry' as car
                   , '894A839' as license_plate
                   , 'Joe Bryant' as owner_name
                   , null color_change_date
                   , null color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('10/1/2019 10:27', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Toyota Camry' as car
                   , '894A839' as license_plate
                   , 'Jennifer Smith' as owner_name
                   , null color_change_date
                   , null color
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('11/30/2019 10:27', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as owner_change_date
                   , 'Toyota Camry' as car
                   , '894A839' as license_plate
                   , 'William Johnson' as owner_name
                   , null color_change_date
                   , null color
                   from dual
                )
select *
from a
order by car, owner_change_date, color_change_date
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle supports `ignore nulls` in window functions, so you can just do:

```
select 
    a.*,
    coalesce(
        color,
        lag(color) ignore nulls over(partition by car order by color_change_date) 
    ) color2
from a
```